# NextUI and Tailwind config file issue

Tags: next.js, frontend, tailwind-css, next.js13, nextui

### Error while configuring nextui in `tailwind.config.js`

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
import {nextui} from "@nextui-org/react";
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  darkMode: "class",
  plugins: [nextui()]
}
```

**Logs**

```
Ready in 3.4s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ⨯ ./app/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[3]!./app/globals.css
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
Import trace for requested module:
./app/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[3]!./app/globals.css
./app/globals.css
 ⨯ ./app/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[3]!./app/globals.css
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
Import trace for requested module:
./app/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[3]!./app/globals.css
./app/globals.css
 ✓ Compiled /favicon.ico in 385ms (323 modules)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjN6Z.png)

I've been trying to set up NextUI with my Next.js project and encountered an issue while configuring it using tailwind.config.js.

I followed the steps outlined in the documentation, but when attempting to configure tailwind.config.js with NextUI, I keep encountering an error.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or successfully configured NextUI with tailwind.config.js in a Next.js project? Any insights or guidance on what might be causing this error would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my config. It works well.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const { nextui } = require("@nextui-org/react");

module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate"), nextui()],
};
```